# Como ver todos los elemntos de una clase en TypeScript

Tags: typescript

ante todo espero que todos estén a salvo del COVID-19. Al lío:

Tengo la siguiente clase que ha hecho un compañero donde guarda una serie de elemento Pock que, para entendernos, son una especie de mensajes con unos atributos:

```
export class PockMessage {
// @ts-ignore
constructor({id, message, location, dateInserted, user, username, media, category, chatAccess}) {
    this.id = id
    this.message = message
    this.location = location
    this.dateInserted = dateInserted
    this.user = user
    this.username = username
    this.media = media
    this.category = category
    this.chatAccess = chatAccess
}

id: any

message: string

location: LatLong

dateInserted: number

user?: string

username?: string

media?: string

category: string

chatAccess: boolean
```

Me gustaría hacer una función en TypeScript que me devolviera en un array todos los valores que tiene el atributo `location` , es decir, por cada elemento de la clase que valor tiene. Es eso posible?

Comment: Esto es offtopic, pero poniendo `private` delante de cada parámetro del constructor, te ahorras las asignaciones. por jemeplo: `constructor(private id, message) {}` es equivalente a `constructor(id, message) { this.id=id; this.message = message;}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías hacer algo como lo siguiente: Usar una propiedad de clase para guardar todos los elementos creados:

```
export class PockMessage {
    static POCK_LOCATIONS = [];
    constructor(id, message, location, dateInserted, user, username, media, category, chatAccess) {
        PockMessage.POCK_LOCATIONS.push(location);
        //...
    }

    static getAllLocations() {
        return PockMessage.POCK_LOCATIONS.slice(); //devolvemos una copia, para evitar que alguien pueda modificar el original
    }

}
```

Comment: De acuerdo, me salia un error raro al hacer el push pero no me ofrecia soluciones la IDE asi que hice // @ts-ignore

Answer (score 0):

```
let arregloPock :PockMessage[]  = [];


let arregloLocation = 
// se aplica un map al arreglo que devuelve un nuevo arreglo con los valores de location
arregloPock.map( e => e.location);
```